# How to create table in SQL Server 2012 using script file generated from SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

How to use a script file generated from SQL Server 2005 and create the same table in SQL Server 2012?

Plus I have a script file for each table, how could I combine them all to generate my database?

Comment: Try to execute the script and see if u face any issues then post the error.

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is a helpful tool for you to test out database actions, and to share schemas/scripts with others from whom you are seeking assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a database on SQL Server 2012 and run each create object script.
If some error or warning arises you can work it by demand.

note the tables got dependencies, so it's a good idea to create that tables in the right order.

You also can create the tables and put a no check in the FKs creation snipets and switch all FKs to check once all tables ar in place.

Also it's good to create all tables before creating the views, etc.